# Equality in singletons for star kind

Tags: haskell

I did in ghci:

```
> :set -XTypeOperators

> import Data.Proxy
> import Data.Type.Equality
> import Data.Singletons.Prelude

> :let p1 = Proxy :: Proxy (Int == Int)
> :let p2 = Proxy :: Proxy (Int :== Int)

> :t p1
p1 :: Proxy 'True
> :t p2
p2 :: Proxy (Int :== Int)
```

Why in the second case type is not calculated? Can I workaround it somehow? Can I make an instance for class `PEq` (where `:==` is defined)?

(ghc 7.10.3)

Update:
I found how to make an instance. Are there some reasons why it is not included?

```
> instance PEq ('KProxy :: KProxy *) where { type (:==) x y = x == y }
```

or simple (as pointed by [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) in comments)

```
> instance PEq ('KProxy :: KProxy *)
```

or import this instance from TypeRepStar:

```
> import Data.Singletons.TypeRepStar()
```

Comment: You wouldn't even need the type definition; it defaults to exactly what you wrote.

Comment: My guess: they forgot to add the instance.

Comment: It's intended and [here's](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/106) the explanation. It's clear from the extended discussion that a poly-kinded `==` is bad, but it's still not quite clear to me why the `*` instance isn't included by default.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks for pointed that out. But the reason is unclear to me too. If I understand correct, user's instance for `*` could be implemented for requried set of types, not for all `*`-types. Probably with better performance? Is it really important here?

Comment: @DmitryOlshansky since you found the answer, you should post it and accept it so this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a reason for not including instance for `PEq` for kind `*` in `singletons` are similar to not including poly-kinded instances for `Eq` in `base`. It is described [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ad4428ddd33f80a883a268dc31f5a2ef68330161/libraries/base/Data/Type/Equality.hs#L157). Such instance too common and if it exists we can't describe e.g. equalities of type arguments by result of type functions. For example:

```
Succ n == Succ m = n == m
```

For workaround in case of `singletons` one can define it:

```
instance PEq ('KProxy :: KProxy *)
```

Or just use it:

```
import Data.Singletons.TypeRepStar()
```